# htaccess - Redirect root pages to folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

**What I have**

```
http://www.my-domain.com/my-product1/
http://www.my-domain.com/another-product/
http://www.my-domain.com/about-us/
```

**What I want**

```
http://www.my-domain.com/product/my-product1/
http://www.my-domain.com/product/another-product/
http://www.my-domain.com/about-us/
```

**The problems**

- I have about 100+ products.
- The products needs to be redirected to the same URL prefixed with a "folder" called "product". The two first are products.
- I need to exclude pages like "about-us" and others like it.
- The redirect should be 301.

**Question**

How is it done? Would be too long to list redirecting every product manually, I think.

**What I have found out so far**

This might be a good start.

http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/htaccess-301-redirect-an-entire-directory-folder/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^old_dir/(.*) http://www.example.com/new_dir/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: is there a pattern for products name?

Comment: No, that is why I need to exclude them somehow.